# Is Iblis afraid of Allah?

Tags: quran

**Question: If Iblis is afraid of Allah, why does he accept going to Hell in the first place?**

my thinking process:
I thought Iblis was a rebellious devil? Why would he say at the end of the verse 'i am scared of allah, because he is severe in punishment?'

Iblis knows he is going to Hell. So I suppose he wants the least punishment there? Is that it? He doesn't want to add more punishment to himself so he doesn't directly cause the evil? Just the temptation?
Is my thinking here correct? That basically Iblis envies Adam too much, and too prideful to let this pass by Allah, and is too upset that Allah dishonored him after all his hard work to earn his status among the angels, that he was asked to bow to a being made of dirt, so he wants to overwhelm humans with temptations and help in sending as many to hell as possible with him as a revenge to Allah. That Iblis I guess doesn't care about Paradise? His pleasure is derived from acting as an devil god on earth.

**Quran 8:48**
When the Satan made their deeds look beautiful to their eyes, and said, “None of the people can overpower you today, and I am a protector for you.” But, when the two groups faced each other, he turned back on his heels and said, “I am quit of you. I am seeing what you do not see. **I am scared of Allah, and Allah is severe in punishment.**”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iblis promised Quraish help on the day of Badr ("I am a protector for you"). Then, when the time came, he ran away and did not help them in any way.

And he gave this statement as an excuse: "I am seeing what you do not see. I am scared of Allah, and Allah is severe in punishment."

What he "sees that they do not see" is the descent of the angels to help the Muslims.

When he said, "I am scared of Allah," it is possible he is lying and giving it as a false excuse because he knows he has no power to help them. He clearly does not fear Allah enough to overcome his pride at most other times.

It is also possible he became terrified seeing the angels descend and thought it was Qiyamah and that is why he said it. Allah knows best.

Comment: I think he does fear Allah. But his pride is much higher than fear.